# Why open debug mode, ajax code will often appear xhr.status=="0"?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I use this code to get error message from flask.

flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
import os

@app.route('/uploadVideo', methods=['POST'])
def uploadVideo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            f = request.files['file']
            basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
            upload_path = os.path.join(basepath, 'static'+os.sep+f.filename)
            f.save(upload_path)
            videoSrc ='static/' + f.filename
            return videoSrc
        except Exception as ex:
            return jsonify(user='user1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=9001,debug=True)
```

js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: form_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:9001/uploadVideo",
    success: function(result) {
        var player = document.getElementById("myVideo_1");
        var mp4vid = document.getElementById("video_source_1");
        player.pause();
        $(mp4vid).attr("src", result);
        player.load();
        player.play();
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        if(xhr.status=="0"){
        alert("error!");
        }else{alert("error code:"+xhr.status)}
    },
});
```

When I use no debug mode：

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=9001)
```

There is no error,but when I use debug mode:

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=9001,debug=True)
```

ajax error function xhr.status is always `0`,why?